# Старт Xamarin Сервер-Клиент

Tags: c#, xamarin

Необходим старт в данной теме. 
Для начала, хотелось бы создать AVD*+PC(клиент-сервер).
Затем уже реализовать через wifi.

Есть кто подсказать как правильно реализовать (что нужно знать/изучить), а лучше примеры кода/github.

*
AVD - android virtual device

Answer (score 0):

Клиент-сервер на мобильном устройстве не будет ничем отличатся от любого другого проекта. (API + HTTP запрос)

Все что надо для старта тут:
https://github.com/xamarin/dev-days-labs

HandsOnLab для Azure (как сервер)

Есть там же в демо пример для погоды.
Увидите процесс запроса погоды от стороннего сервиса.